# Visual Studio Code snippet for converting between a display and inline equation

Tags: vscode, ide

I use VS Code as my IDE for writing LaTeX documents. Often, I would like to switch an inline equation to a display equation and vice versa. In VS Code, you can define snippets that perform this sort of thing. What is a snippet for performing this operation?

In particular, given highlighted text in the form

```
something$<my equation>$something
```

I want to convert it to

```
something\[
    <my equation>
\]something
```

and the same thing in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here are snippets that perform the desired operation. Note that all backslashes `\` in the regular equations are duplicated (`\\`) to escape them *except* for the backslash in `\n` (not sure why, tbh).

```
"Convert to display equation":{
    "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)\\$(.*)\\$(.*)/$1\\[\n\t$2\n\\]$3/}",
    ],
    "description": "Convert an inline equation to a display equation."
},
"Convert to inline equation":{
    "body": [
        // Regular expression (unescaped): (.*)\\\[\s*\n*\s*(.*?)\s*\n*\s*\\\](.*)
        // - "\s*\n*\s*" matches line breaks with space around it.
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)\\\\\\[\\s*\n*\\s*(.*?)\\s*\n*\\s*\\\\\\](.*)/$1$$2$$3/}",
    ],
    "description": "Convert a display equation to an inline equation."
}
```

You can setup keyboard shortcuts as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets).